# webPart ajax tab

Tags: c#, ajax, sharepoint-2010

I am creating some SharePoint 2010 visual webparts.  I can't see an ajax tab in toolpane.

What do I need to do in order to add ajax tools to my visual webpart?

Comment: are you referring to these tools? http://bcahub.shareittips.com/ty-bca/asp-net/asp-theory/install-ajax-toolkit-in-visual-studio-net-2008/

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX toolbox is most likely disabled because out of the box, it does not work with sharepoint visual webparts.

See these links for how to setup your project (and the issues you will encounter):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648708.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx

http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-To-Create-AJAX-enabled-SharePoint-Web-Part-with-UpdatePanel-and-UpdateProgress-in-10-minutes.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/9c906e16-8291-49ce-aa09-36c9d72a8247